# Getting the variable name (IdentifierInfo?) from clang Expr* object of arguments for function calls

Tags: clang, llvm, static-analysis

I'm trying to get function call sequences using clang's Analyzer framework (With checkers and such).

I wrote a `Checker` that uses the `checkPreCall` method to handle function calls. I'm trying to look at simple function calls like `f(x, y)`, and I want to see the name of the variable I'm passing to the function.

Using the fact that a `Expr` is a type of `Stmt`, I used the `printPretty` function to get the variable name, but obviously if the argument is `x+2` or something like that I get `x+2` as the output.

Is there a better way to retrieve the name of the variable, or even find out whether it's a simple expression (`x`) or a complex one (`x+2`)?